# Java Concurrency - Wrong Result When Using Synchronized Keyword

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm, synchronized

I am sorry for this basic question but I am so curious why I am not getting the correct result for the below code. I have a basic Account class which has 3 non-synchronized and 3 synchronized methods that do the same jobs. My expectation is to calculate the correct result when I use the synchronized keyword but when i run the application unfortunately I am getting a wrong error. What I am missing here? Thanks in advance guys!

Here's the `Account` class

```
public class Account {
    private double balance;

    public Account(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public boolean rawWithDraw(int amount) {
        if (balance >= balance) {
            balance = balance - amount;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void rawDeposit(int amount) {
        balance = balance + amount;
    }

    public double getRawBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public boolean safeWithDraw(final int amount) {
        synchronized (this){
            if (balance >= amount) {
                balance = balance - amount;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void safeDeposit(final int amount) {
        synchronized (this) {
            balance = balance + amount;
        }
    }

    public double getSafeBalance() {
        synchronized (this) {
            return balance;
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the main application

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account1 = new Account(0);
        Thread tA = new Thread(() -> account1.safeDeposit(70));
        Thread tB = new Thread(() -> account1.safeDeposit(50));
        tA.setName("thread-A");
        tB.setName("thread-B");
        tA.start();
        tB.start();

        System.out.println("The balance is : " + account1.getRawBalance());
    }
}
```

And when I run the code, sometimes it prints `70`, sometimes `0` and sometimes `120`. What causing this?

[image]

Comment: You're not waiting for your depositing threads to finish before you check the balance.

Comment: Aside comment: typo in `rawWithdraw` method - `balance >= balance` should always be true

Comment: So basically I should add  `tA.join()` and `tB.join()` after `start` methods? But when I wait for depositing threads to finish before check the balance, it gives the correct result without `synchronized` methods as well. Why it's like that?

Comment: When something isn’t thread safe, it isn’t guaranteed to fail in a predictable way. It means the behavior is undefined. It might give the correct result sometimes, or always by coincidence on a particular configuration. Unfortunately, it can’t be simply checked by running the code, thread safety needs to be analyzed.

Comment: Thanks all for responding the question. :)

Comment: Letting aside the specific problem of your test program, the class is broken *in general*. To make the class thread safe, *all access* to the mutable variable must be guarded with the same construct, in other words, those “raw” methods accessing `balance` without `synchronized(this)` should not exist. By the way, the word is “withdraw”, not “with draw”, so using an uppercase D is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You have not included `getRawBalance()` as a synchronized method, so it is allowed to run concurrently with either of the two synchronized methods.  You can therefore see the result before either method executes, after both methods execute, or in between one and the other, giving four different possible outcomes.